# <v-otp-input> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

im working on a nuxt project and im using vuetify as a UI framework.
i tried using v-otp-input but i get this error in my console.

all the vuetify elements are working fine but this one doesn't , what should i do ?

here is my code

```
 <v-otp-input
      :error-messages="codeErrorMsg"
      v-model="password"
      type="password"
      length="5"
      dark
    ></v-otp-input>
```

ps:im looking for somthing like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input you could use this package if your vuetify version is not equal to or higher than 2.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was because of vuetify version (**vuetify version  must be 2.6.0 or higher**)

**for updating vuetify**:

1.Run npm info vuetify to lookup for the list of versions that they have.

```
npm info vuetify
```

2.install the specific version that you want with the following
for example:

```
npm install --save vuetify@2.6.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the last Vuetify version (2.6.6) you have to wrap your page or your layout into a  component: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-app/

```
<template>
  <v-app>
      <v-otp-input
        :error-messages="codeErrorMsg"
        v-model="password"
        type="password"
        length="5"
        dark
      ></v-otp-input>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, using vuetify v2.6.9, with vue-cli-plugin vuetify. I tried manually importing the component in my component and it worked:

```html
<template>
    <v-otp-input
      class="
        font-weight-bold
        text-uppercase
        btn-primary
        bg-gradient-primary
        py-2
        px-6
        me-2
        mt-7
        mb-2
        w-100
      "
      color="#5e72e4"
      v-model="otp"
      :disabled="loading"
      @finish="onFinish"
    ></v-otp-input>
</template>

<script>
   import { VOtpInput } from "vuetify/lib";
   export default {
      name: "sign-up-verify",
      components: { VOtpInput },
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vuetify [`<v-opt-input>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/otp-input/#usage) component and override a bit its css for your needs.

```
<v-otp-input
  length="6"
  plain
  type="number"
></v-otp-input>
```

To edit the css style of the component, it's not an easy task as you have to check on the browser debugger what are the classes applied to the component and what elements it includes.
But it's doable :)

Comment: i tried that  but i get this error: <v-otp-input> - did you register the component correctly?

Comment: @ArianFm how did you imported/installed the components so far? There is nothing more in the documentation?

Comment: @kissu all the component of vuetify are working fine but this one show this error in my console , its so weird , i read this document https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/otp-input/#usage , But it's like the rest of the components and has nothing more to explain

Comment: Could it be because of the vuetify version?

Comment: @ArianFm which version of Nuxt and Vuetify do you use?